# Angular 2 CLI ng build --watch set cofiguration

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Is it possible to set configuration, or tell my ng build --watch command how to bundle and minify files on disk every time I change something ?

Comment: have you tried ng serve?

Comment: As for as I know 'ng serve' starts web service and use files from memory. I need bundled files on disk and to be bundled every time I changed something. Is it possible with ng serve ?

Comment: No it's not with ng serve

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to watch the files:

```
ng build --watch
```

There is also an option to poll the files. The following example would poll the files every 10 seconds:

```
ng build --poll 10000
```

source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build